# How to use multi-language output from database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql database table called `COUNTRY`

```
CountryCode LanguageCode  CountryName
AG           JPN           アンティグア
```

I trying to show this table in my php page, But output is coming like below

```
CountryCode LanguageCode  CountryName
AG           JPN           ?????????
```

Japanese word not showing as per the table. I using `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` in my header

i try to enter Japanese `(アンティグア)` direct to the `HTML`, but it showing correct.

why it not show correctly from database table?

Comment: what is your DB connection charset? and database charset?

Comment: i am new in mysql .. id't no currently. how i find out this?

Comment: `echo mysql_client_encoding($connection_variable);`

Answer (score 0):

You must query the database first like this:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); // use mysqli_ !
```

After you've run this query you can run your regular "select" etc.. Also, make sure the collation of the fields is `utf8_general_ci`

Comment: @user2656837 was the problem solved? if so can you post the correct solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you did not mark it as UTF-8. The fields have to be declared as 'utf8'. If you have phpMyAdmin this should be easy to change (under structure).